# pie chart doesn't appear with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I used chart.js to make a pie chart but it doesn't appear. I even used a pie script online and it never showed up.

please who can read my script and tell me if I have a mistake, I need some assistance thank you.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); let labels = ['Pizza ', 'Taco ', 'Hot Dog ', 'Sushi ']; let colorHex = ['#FB3640', '#EFCA08', '#43AA8B', '#253D5B'];
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'pie',
data: {
    datasets: [{
    data: [30, 10, 40, 20],
    backgroundColor: colorHex
    }],
    labels: labels
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
    },
    plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'start',
        offset: -10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 25,
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
        return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        font: {
        weight: 'bold',
        size: '10'
        },
        formatter: (value) => {
        return value + ' %';
        }
    }
    }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have created a codepen with your code and it's working. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/oNPJwgp

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because of this line

```js
Document let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); let labels = ['Pizza ', 'Taco ', 'Hot Dog ', 'Sushi ']; let colorHex = ['#FB3640', '#EFCA08', '#43AA8B', '#253D5B'];
```

You say `Document let ctx = ...` but thats invalid JS, you will need to remove the `Document` keyword so you will get the following:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); let labels = ['Pizza ', 'Taco ', 'Hot Dog ', 'Sushi ']; let colorHex = ['#FB3640', '#EFCA08', '#43AA8B', '#253D5B'];
```

If you do that it will work fine

Comment: I apologize I don't know how it appeared in the post but it doesn't exist in the real script